# R mutate across defined variables and change values based on another column

Tags: r, conditional-operator, mutate

I would like to replace values with "NA" in a data frame but only if a value in a specified column is out of a defined range.

Here's an example:
Assuming I have 5 columns in a data frame (called a, b, c, d, e). I want to check if column "a" is out of a certain range (for example *a < 2 or a > 5*) and if that is true, I would like to assign "NA" to the values in columns *a, b* and *c* but values in colums *d* and *e* should stay the same.

```
a <- c(1, 3, 6, 1, 4)
b <- c(4, 5, 7, 5, 3)
c <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 2)
d <- c(3, 3, 3, 5, 6)
e <- c(2, 2, 4, 2, 1)

data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d,e))
```

So the desired output would be:

```
a  b  c  d  e
NA NA NA 3  2
3  5  2  3  2
NA NA NA 3  4
NA NA NA 5  2
4  3  2  6  1
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
variables <- c("a", "b", "c")

new_data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(variables), if_else(a < 2 | a > 5, NA_character_, ""))
```

Another idea was to put it in a for-Loop:

```
for (x in variables) {
  new_data <- data %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(variables)), if_else(a < 2 | a > 5, NA_character_, x))
}
```

But these solutions only add a column and do not change the values accordingly.

This is a simplified example. I would like to apply the solution to a greater number of variables. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, but you need to take care how you provide your function. You can use tidyverse formula interface like this (note that `.x` will refer to the column you are currently mutating):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(c(a, b, c), ~ if_else(!between(a, 2, 5), NA_real_, .x)))

#    a  b  c d e
# 1 NA NA NA 3 2
# 2  3  5  2 3 2
# 3 NA NA NA 3 4
# 4 NA NA NA 5 2
# 5  4  3  2 6 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Why did you use NA_real_ instead of NA_character_?

Comment: `if_else` is typed, i.e. it expects that the `FALSE` and the `TRUE` part return the same type. As the `FALSE`  part will return a number, the `TRUE`  part must also return a "number", thus you need the number typed `NA`, which is `NA_real_`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the column a, then set columns a, b, c to NA:

```
data[ data$a < 2 | data$a > 5, c("a", "b", "c") ] <- NA

data
#    a  b  c d e
# 1 NA NA NA 3 2
# 2  3  5  2 3 2
# 3 NA NA NA 3 4
# 4 NA NA NA 5 2
# 5  4  3  2 6 1
```